# WP CLI install list of plugins from YML file wp-cli.local.yml

Tags: php, git, wordpress

First off a bit of background information. We want to keep our git repo as clean as possible and only include code that we write therefore when using wordpress we exclude all wordpress core code and any plugins not written by ourselves such as contact form 7.

However this poses a problem when a developer checks out the repo and there is very bare repo usually just consisting of the theme.

Therefore I want to use [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) and within the repo to also contain a wp-cli.local.yml file with all of the wordpress configuration data so after a developer has checked out the repo they can simply run:

```
wp core download
wp core config
wp core install
```

This works perfectly so far but next I am attempting to install a list of plugins specified in the wp-cli.local.yml file by simply running

```
wp plugin install
```

However this does not look at the yml file and simply asks to specify the plugin. Upon [reading the docs](http://wp-cli.org/config/) it seems as though this isn't possible but wanted to check with fellow developers to see if this is indeed the case.

Here is an example of my wp-cli.local.yml file

`path: public_html/
url: http://example.dev
user: admin
core skip-plugins:
  - hello
core skip-themes:
  - twentyfifteen
  - twentyfourteen
  - twentythirteen
core download:
  locale: en_GB
core config:
    dbname: example
    dbuser: root
    dbpass:
    extra-php: |
        define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
        define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 10 );
core install:
    title: Example
    admin_user: admin
    admin_password: admin
    admin_email: admin@example.dev
plugin install:
  - wordpress-seo
  - wp-scss
  - wp-sync-db`

I understand what I am after is similar to yeoman generator but would like to use just one system to save complicated installations.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. There is no option for WP-CLI to install and activate plugins based off a YML.

Therefore I made an extension to allow for a quick installation of WP based off a YML.
https://github.com/philcook/squick